# How can i use nodejs "request" library for accessing the threads in the gmail account

Tags: node.js, google-api, gmail-api

I have to specifically use the request module.
I have the refresh token as well as access token.

```
request({
            method: "GET",
           uri:"https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/threads",
            headers: {
                "access_token": 'access_token',
                "refresh_token": 'refresh_token',
                "token_type": 'Bearer',
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
        },
        function(err, response, body) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err); // Failure
            } else {
                console.log(response);
               // done(null);// Success!
            }
        });
```

whenever i run this there is an 401 error which says login required.
Also how can i use specific query "q" and send it with the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about following sample?

In order to use this, please include `https://mail.google.com/` to the scope, and enable Gmail API at Google API console. If you have already done them, please ignore them.

Also I included "q" in the script. The detail information is https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list. Please check it, too.

**Script :**

```
var request = require('request');
request({
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/threads',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer ### your access token ###"
        },
        qs: {
            "q": "from:### mail address ###", // For example, a filter is added by ``from``.
            "fields": "threads"
        }
    },
    function (err, response, body) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err); // Failure
        } else {
            console.log(body);
           // done(null);// Success!
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [NodeJS Quickstart for Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs). It already includes the login implementation:

```
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var auth = new googleAuth();
  var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}
```

You use 'q' when you make calls to [Users.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) or 
[Users.threads.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list). It includes JS samples for your reference:

```
request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
          'userId': userId,
          'pageToken': nextPageToken,
          'q': query
        });
```

> 'q' only return messages matching the specified query. Supports the
>   same query format as the Gmail search box. For example,
>   "from:someuser@example.com rfc822msgid: is:unread".